# Handling ConnectionString credentials C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008, connection-string, credentials

I have an application that needs to connect to an MS SQL db.
Normally I would have used SSPI, BUT in this case, I need to impersonate a different user than the current user.

How would I go about this?
the only constraints I have is

1. SSPI is not an option.
2. Hardcoding credentials is, also, not an option.
3. Credentials needs to  be saved locally
4. it's a desktop application
5. Credentials needs to be stored at runtime

if all else fails, i'll just SSPI and design my way out of it, but id like to hear what my options are first.

Comment: Aren't 2 and 3 contradictory? Isn't saving credentials locally hard coding?

Comment: I mean hardcoding as in, hardcoding it into my exe. Locally as in, locally on the machine

Comment: Would app.config be considered hard coding?

Comment: Could you just run the app as the user you need to impersonate?

Comment: Would this be a machine-wide, application-wide or user-specific configuration?

Comment: @Blam No, special "service account" for ConnectionString.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Application-Wide

Comment: So this is a domain or local account that you want to impersonate?  Or do you want a userID and password in the connection string (not integrated security on SQL)?

Comment: UserID and password in connectionstring or integrated security through impersonation - either way works for me

Comment: How are you currently parametrizing the server name and DB name? Just apply the same criteria for user+pass/sspi and you're done.

Comment: @Alejandro that would be hardcoding it into my application, I was thinking of constructing the connectionstring at runtime, with servername+Dbname hardcoded and adding in the username and pass

Comment: Any security issues other than just not store the credentials in the app?  If you are going to store credential in a file they are not really associated with a special "service account".

Comment: The registry is still an option.

Comment: Tha a look at [Configuring Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kza1yk3a.aspx)

Comment: @AlexInTime I like the option of building the connection string at runtime (`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is a good help here), but you should really store DB/server together with user/pass, even if you know that "those never change" :D

Comment: how do i use sqlconnectionstringbuilder with a NT user?!

Answer (score -2):

Just store your connection string in app.config.

Comment: app.config can't be edited at runtime right? - edited my question

Comment: app.config does not exist at run time. But a configuration file existes and there are APIs for that.

Comment: Even though this would work, saving the connection string as a whole implies storing the password as plain-text, and that's a big NO-NO. Consider at least encrypting before storing.

Comment: I am hashing the password, no matter how I choose to store it